# What happens after a car finishes an F1 race

Tags: formula-1

After crossing the finishing line in F1, how much further ahead do drivers go?  Obviously they can't stop right at the finishing line.  Are there any regulations here? How do they exit the track? is it standard across all circuits? Do they go for another round?  It's never been clear to me.  The video  is always cut after they cross the line and/or the perspective does not make it clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The finish procedure is covered by Article 43 of the [Formula One Sporting Regulations](https://www.fia.com/sites/default/files/2021_formula_1_sporting_regulations_-_iss_5_-_2020-12-16.pdf) (found on page 48).

Articles 43.1 and 43.3 state, in part:

> A chequered flag will be the end-of-race signal and will be shown at the [finish] line as soon as the leading car has covered the full race distance [...] After receiving the end-of-race signal all cars must proceed on the circuit directly to the post-race parc fermé ... without any assistance (except that of the marshals if necessary).

[Parc fermé](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parc_ferm%C3%A9) is a secure area of the pit complex where the cars are lined up after the race, so they can be inspected to ensure that they comply with the regulations. My understanding is that after crossing the finish line, the cars make their way around the circuit for a cooldown lap/lap of honour, and then enter parc fermé via the usual pit lane entrance. Should they break down or run out of fuel before they get there, the marshals will help tow it back to the pits.

Comment: *"the cars make their way around the circuit"* There are exceptions, like Spa (or Nurburgring in the old days).